# API Query in Powershell not running when not logged in

Tags: powershell, rest, microsoft-graph-api, windows-server

I am trying to figure out why a powershell script I run from a windows server is not completing when I am not logged in. The power shell script is used to grab a call report from Flowroute using REST API JSON. It then downloads the report file as a zip file and 7zip extracts into a directory. Finally, it then sends an email using Micrsoft Graph API app registration with the file to certain email addresses. I have this run from task scheduler in Windows Server 2016 which runs fine when I manually run it but running on a schedule while I am not logged in does not work. I assume something with querying REST API or Microsoft Graph will not run when not logged in but not sure where to go from here. Below is my code and I have also included a image of the task scheduler setup.

```
#Ensure that all TLS protocols are supported
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls, Tls11, Tls12, Ssl3"



#Creates variables for the 1st of the month for last month and 1st of the month for current month.
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$FirstDayOfCurrentMonth = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month $CurrentDate.Month -Year $CurrentDate.Year -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
$FirstDayOfPreviousMonth = (Get-Date -Day 1 -Month ($CurrentDate.Month - 1) -Year $CurrentDate.Year).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
$DestNumber = "phone-number"


#Connects to Flowroute REST API with token created in flowroute.com uses variables from previous step
$BaseUrl = "https://" + "api.flowroute.com/v2/cdrs/exports/"
    $Headers = @{
        "Content-Type" = "application/vnd.api+json"
        "Authorization"  = "code"
    }

$body = @"
{
  `"data`": {
    `"type`": `"cdrexport`",
    
    
    `"attributes`": {

      `"filter_parameters`": {
        `"start_call_start_time`": `"$FirstDayOfPreviousMonth`",
        `"start_call_end_time`": `"$FirstDayOfCurrentMonth`",
        `"destination_numbers`": ["$DestNumber"]
      }
    }
  }
}
"@

#POSTS query to flowroute API to create report based on previous variables. 
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $BaseUrl -Method "POST" -Headers $headers -Body $body

    $response | Get-member

    
     # Sleep to allow API to run
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    # Based on documentation, endpoint to query is "/cdrs/exports/:cdrexport_id"
    # Gathering ID from previous query
    $URI = $BaseURL + $response.data.id
    $DateForFile = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

    # Status of your query via a GET request, no body needed
    $status = Invoke-RestMethod $URI -Method "GET" -Headers $headers

    # download URL
    $download_url = $status.data.attributes.download_url

    # Download the report created from POST query
    $output = "C:\Temp\Report-File${DateForFile}.csv.gz"
    Invoke-WebRequest -uri $download_url -outfile $output

    #Using 7zip extracts the downloaded file so it's not encrypted

& "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z" x "C:\Temp\Report-file-${DateForFile}.csv.gz" -o"C:\Temp" -y


#Send the downloaded report to whoever the below Mailrecipient variable is set to


#Define Graph API variables from Azure App Registration
$clientID = "ID"
$Clientsecret = "Secret"
$tenantID = "ID"

#Define which mailbox to send from and recipient
$MailSender = "email"
$Mailrecipient = "email"
$CCRecipient1 = "email"
$CCRecipient2 = "email"

#Connect to GRAPH API
$tokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    Client_Id     = $clientId
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
}
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenBody

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($tokenResponse.access_token)"
    "Content-type"  = "application/json"
}

#Locates the downloaded report to attach to email
$Attachment = "C:\Temp\report-file-${DateForFile}.csv"
#Get File Name and Base64 string
$FileName=(Get-Item -Path $Attachment).name
$base64string = [Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Attachment))


$MessageParams = @{
    "URI"         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$MailSender/sendMail"
    "Headers"     = $headers
    "Method"      = "POST"
    "ContentType" = 'application/json'
    "Body" = (@{
          "message" = @{
          "subject" = "Report"
          "body"    = @{
               "contentType" = 'HTML' 
               "content"     = "Email message."} 

          "toRecipients" = @(
          @{
          "emailAddress" = @{"address" = $Mailrecipient }
        } )

          "CCRecipients" = @(
          @{
          "emailAddress" = @{"address" = $CCrecipient1 }
        } 
        @{
          "emailAddress" = @{"address" = $CCrecipient2 }
        }
        
        )

        "attachments" = @(      
              @{      
                "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment"
                "name" = $FileName
                "contentType" = "text/plain"
                "contentBytes" = "$base64string"          
                }        
        )
}
}) | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 6
}
# Send the message
Invoke-RestMethod @Messageparams

#Deletes the downloaded report
(Get-ChildItem -File C:\Temp).Delete()
```

[Link to Task Scheduler image setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpVMg.jpg)

If anyone has some insight why this will not complete unattended at a scheduled time please let me know as it would be nice to have this automated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With my experience this happens because we are losing our session when we log off and this script fixes it. Make sure to run this script using "run with powershell" to sign out instead of using the sign out option in windows server.

```
# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal = new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal ($myWindowsID)

# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

# Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
if (-not $myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
  # We are not running "as Administrator" - so relaunch as administrator
  # Create a new process object that starts PowerShell
  $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";

  # Specify the current script path and name as a parameter
  $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;

  # Indicate that the process should be elevated
  $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

  # Start the new process
  [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

  # Exit from the current, unelevated, process
  exit
}

# Run your code that needs to be elevated here
$session = (qwinsta | Where-Object { $_ -match $env:USERNAME }) -replace '\s+',' ' -split ' ' | Select-Object -Index 0
$session = $session.Replace(">", "")
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
tscon $session /dest:console
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Could you clarify what you mean when you mentioned "Make sure to run this script using "run with powershell" to sign out?" Currently the action I have for task scheduler is to just start power shell using this C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe. Then I save and have it run at a certain time. Is there another way of signing out that allows your script and session to remain?

Comment: Because you mentioned that task scheduler does not run when you're logged out, this script leaves a session when you sign out. Forgot to mention to save this file a powershell script (.ps1) file and right click it and select run with powershell.

Comment: Sorry again but how would I be able to right click and run with powershell if running from task scheduler? Since I'm using task scheduler to run at certain times and I will not be logged in when the script is run, won't this have the same issue? Thanks again.

Comment: The script I sent you is a separate powershell script that won't run in task scheduler. You just need to run it after you set up your task scheduler jobs.